# Why does this backtracking algorithm to compute all permutations of a simple list not return all permutations?

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        res = []
        length = len(nums) - 1
        def dfs(nums, l):
            # base case
            if l == length:
                res.append(nums)
            for i in range(l, length):
              # swap
              temp = nums[l]
              nums[l] = nums[i]
              nums[i] = temp

              dfs(nums, l+1)

              # backtrack
              temp = nums[l]
              nums[l] = nums[i]
              nums[i] = temp
            return 
        dfs(nums, 0)
        return res
```

The output for [1,2,3] is a list of lists where each element is itself [1,2,3] I don't understand.

Comment: It looks like you might be mutating the same `nums` list each time instead of creating a new list for each permutation.

Comment: @MichaelButscher yeah that answers my question but why do I feel like this should work? What is wrong with mutating the list each recursive call ... since I'm backtracking and returning list to original position and saving state when i == length

Comment: That isn't wrong but storing a reference to the same list object in `res` again and again is. Replace `res.append(nums)` by `res.append(nums[:])` to append a copy.

Comment: @MichaelButscher got it now thanks for your explanation., Here I thought I knew Python :(

Comment: Using the debugging tips from [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) will help you understand in more detail what is happening in your original code.